# Fatal Error When Creating Navigation Drawer - RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm attempting to create a Navigation Drawer in my application however when I attempt to do so I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

The error seems to reference the following line (721):

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
```

which I've confirmed, refers to:

```
private android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
mDrawerLayout = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
```

and:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

So I'm unsure why I'm getting an error regarding a RelativeLayout.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

### Full XML:

http://pastebin.com/a08mwhsT

Full Source:

http://pastebin.com/82spas1W

### LogCat:

```
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514): Process: com.example.app, PID: 4514
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1129)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1379)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.example.app.Home.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Home.java:721)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2556)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-06 15:18:19.418: E/AndroidRuntime(4514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line to

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START);
```

and add to your ListView in XML

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

finally remove it from `RelativeLayout` - it's causing the problem:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), it must be set on list.

Comment: I tried as you suggested: http://pastebin.com/H4fQPWKk 

However it is still crashing on the same line. :(